# jquery draggable to all apprise function

Tags: jquery, draggable

I need help with the following:

1.)  How can i put the function $('div.appriseOuter').draggable(); for all 'apprise' functions?   i need to put the on each apprise function

2.) When you click "click me" it should pop-up the dialog box "Drag me #1" - then when you hit the ENTER key, it goes to dialog box "Drag me #2" then When you hit ENTER again, the dialog box "Drag me #3" did not show up. But when you normally CLICK not ENTER, it proceeds to the dialog box "Drag me #3"

```
 My JsFiddle is
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/jmcausing/sNuUN/6/)

Answer (score 0):

For your question no. 1, you can take use of jquery chaining and do it in your plugin itself.

```
$('.appriseOuter').draggable().append('<div class="appriseInner"></div>');
```

For your question no. 2, it happens because you have written this code in your plugin

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if($('.appriseOverlay').is(':visible')){
        if(e.keyCode == 13) { 
            $('.aButtons > button[value="ok"]').click(); 
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 27) { 
              $('.aButtons > button[value="cancel"]').click(); }
        }
});
```

and it binds the keybind events everytime you call appraise. Moving this outside you plugin so it is called only once solves the problem. Here is your updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sNuUN/7/)